# Google Picasa error while retrieving albums

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, picasa

I am developing a service over Google Picasa so i do user Authentication over google authentication which I redirect users to google to login and then return to my application with accesstoken 
then accesstoken will be stored in some where in database for each user to recognize each one the next time he trying to use the service 
the problem is when i am trying to use the accesstoken to create PicasaService i got an (403) Forbidden error here is my code

```
GAuthSubRequestFactory authFactory = new GAuthSubRequestFactory("lh2", "my application name");
        authFactory.AccountType = "GOOGLE_OR_HOSTED";
        authFactory.Token = accessToken;
PicasaService service = new PicasaService(authFactory.ApplicationName);
        service.RequestFactory = authFactory;
AlbumQuery query = new AlbumQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri("default"));

        PicasaFeed feed = picasaService.Query(query);

        foreach (PicasaEntry entry in feed.Entries)
        {
            string title = entry.Title.Text;
            AlbumAccessor ac = new AlbumAccessor(entry);
            uint numberOfPhotosPerAlbum = ac.NumPhotos;
        }
```